# perl inconsistent negative zero result

Tags: perl, floating-point

I have the following code :

```
my $m=0;
my $e =0 ;
my $g=0;

my $x=  sprintf( "%0.1f", (0.6*$m+ 0.7 * $e-1.5)*$g);

print $x;
```

when I run the script the result is -0.0 and not 0.0 could someone explain why and how i can change it to be 0.0.

Comment: I suppose subtracting -0.0 isn’t what you’re looking for. :) [that was a joke]

Comment: I've deleted the [tag:sprintf] tag (since that's not the cause of the problem) and added [tag:floating-point].

Comment: FWIW, I do not see this on Windows with various `perl`s. See also http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=656432

Comment: Did you find an acceptable solution?

Answer (score 5):

First, this has nothing to do with Perl. It's your processor that's returning -0.0. You'll see this same behaviour in other languages.

---

You ask why, presumably asking why this is useful. Honestly, I don't know. Some scientists and engineers probably take advantage of it.

+0.0 would indicate "zero or something very slightly larger on the positive side".

-0.0 would indicate "zero or something very slightly larger on the negative side."

---

You also ask how to get rid of the sign.

Negative zero is false, so `$x || 0` does the trick.

Answer (score 3):

You've run into something very strange.  My first thought was that you were seeing some very small negative number that `sprintf` rounds to -0.0, but in fact the result of the expression is an actual negative zero.

Here's a simpler program that exhibits the same issue:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $x = -1.0 * 0.0;
my $y = -1.5 * 0.0;
printf "x = %f\n", $x;
printf "y = %f\n", $y;
```

and the output:

```
x = 0.000000
y = -0.000000
```

<strike>My best guess is that `-1.0 * 0.0` is being computed at compile time, but `-1.5 * 0.0` is being computed at execution time, and the computations are yielding different results.</strike>  **EDIT**: Strike that; a modified version of the program that replaces all the constants with function calls has the same behavior.

I can avoid the negative zero display by adding these lines before the `printf` calls:

```
$x += 0.0;
$y += 0.0;
```

but that's ugly.

(Incidentally, I get the same results with the "bleading-edge" version of Perl 5.15.2 from about a month ago.)

A similar C program prints `-0.000000` for both x and y.

**EDIT**: Further experiment shows that multiplying a negative integral value by 0.0 yields 0.0, but multiplying a negative non-integral value by 0.0 yields -0.0.  I've submitted a [Perl bug report](https://rt.perl.org/rt3//Public/Bug/Display.html?id=101262).

Answer (score 1):

Very strange. I note that the problem disappears if you replace `1.5` with a negative integer:

```
$ perl -e '
my @a=(-9.0, -3.0, -2.0, -1.5, -1.2, -1.0, -0.8, -0.5);
for my $a (@a) {
  $bin = join("", map {sprintf("%02x", ord($_))} split(//, pack("d>", $a*0)));
  printf("%4.1f * 0 = %4.1f %s\n", $a, $a*0, $bin);
}'
-9.0 * 0 =  0.0 0000000000000000
-3.0 * 0 =  0.0 0000000000000000
-2.0 * 0 =  0.0 0000000000000000
-1.5 * 0 = -0.0 8000000000000000
-1.2 * 0 = -0.0 8000000000000000
-1.0 * 0 =  0.0 0000000000000000
-0.8 * 0 = -0.0 8000000000000000
-0.5 * 0 = -0.0 8000000000000000
```

All I can think of is to treat -0.0 as a special case:

```
my $ans = (0.6*$m+ 0.7 * $e-1.5)*$g;
my $x=  sprintf("%0.1f", $ans == -0.0 ? 0.0 : $ans)
```

(**EDIT:** This was a dumb suggestion, since `-0.0 == 0.0`.)

I also checked Python's behaviour, which consistently retains the sign, which suggests that the negative sign is not really a bug in Perl, just a little strange (though I'd say that treating integers and non-integers differently *is* a bug):

```
$ python -c '
for a in [-9.0, -3.0, -2.0, -1.5, -1.2, -1.0, -0.8, -0.5]:
  print "%0.1f" % (a*0,)
'
-0.0
-0.0
-0.0
-0.0
-0.0
-0.0
-0.0
-0.0
```

Comment: I don't think your solution works. Did you try it? At least on my system `my $f = 0.0; print "neg zero\n" if $f == -0.0;` prints `neg zero`.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing to see here, move along...

> Zero is represented by the exponent emin - 1 and a zero significand.
>   Since the sign bit can take on two different values, there are two
>   zeros, +0 and -0.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Yes, but the question is why some calculations produce -0.0 and others produce +0.0.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't address the post *directly*, but it does address the "odd" behavior that exists in perl.

---

(I believe) This issue is caused because perl is converting the numbers to *integers* and then using *INTEGER/ALU* math instead of *FP/FPU* math. However, *there is no -0 integer [in two's complement]* -- only an -0 integral which is really a floating point value -- so the floating point value -0.0 is converted to the integer 0 *before* the multiplication :-)

Here is my "demonstration":

```
printf "%.f\n", 2.0 * -0.0;
printf "%.f\n", 1.5 * -0.0;
printf "%.f\n", 1.0 * -0.0;
printf "%.f\n", 1e8 * -0.0;
printf "%.f\n", 1e42 * -0.0;
```

And my "result/reasoning" is:

```
0   # 2.0 -> 2 and -0.0 -> 0: INTEGER math
-0  # 1.5 is not an integral: FP math, no conversions
0   # 1.0 -> 1 and -0.0 -> 0: INTEGER math
0   # 1e8 -> 100000000 and -0.0 -> 0: INTEGER math
-0  # 1e42 is an integral OUTSIDE the range of integers: FP math, no conversions
```

Happy musings.

---

Python does not exhibit these quirks because it has strongly-typed numbers: it will not convert an integral floating point value to an integer prior to a math operation. (Python will still perform standard type-widening.) Try divide by 0.0 (FP, not INTEGER math!) in perl ;-)

Comment: Nit: There is a -0 integer on one's-complement machines

Answer (score 1):

[Data::Float](http://metacpan.org/module/Data%3a%3aFloat) has some useful information as well as routines to check if a floating point value is zero.

The short answer is, when dealing with floating point, you cannot assume algebraic identities will be preserved.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Float qw(float_is_zero);

my $m = 0;
my $e = 0;
my $g = 0;

my $result = (0.6 * $m + 0.7 * $e - 1.5) * $g;
$result = 0.0 if float_is_zero($result);

my $x = sprintf( "%0.1f", $result);

print $x;
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer: use the absolute value function, `abs()`

Code

```
printf "%f\n", -0.0;
printf "%f\n", abs(-0.0);
```

Perl 5.10.1

```
-0.000000
0.000000
```

Perl 5.12.1

```
-0.000000
0.000000
```

Perl 6 (rakudo-2010.08)

```
0.000000
0.000000
```

IEEE 754 standard

> abs(x) copies a floating-point operand x to a destination in the same
>   format, setting the sign bit to 0 (positive).

**EDIT (addressing [Justin's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/193359/justin) feedback):**

```
my $result = possible_negative_zero();
$result = abs($result) if $result == 0.0; # because -0.0 == 0.0
printf "%f\n", $result;
```

Comment: That's liable to cause problems when the desired result could be a negative number.